# Core Data: Why create a custom persistent store?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, core-data

I have been working through the book "Pro Core Data" and I'm to the point in Chapter 3 "Creating your own custom persistent store". The authors don't really talk about why I'd want to create a custom persistent store. The only place where the issue is addressed:

> In some cases, the default store types don’t best accomplish what you
>   are trying to achieve.

Which doesn't really answer my question. It seems that one of the built in types should address any issues if you do not want to use the default version of SQL provided. Creating custom store types seems to go against the spirit of Core Data where I just worry about storing objects, not how they are stored.

I'd like to see some concrete examples of why the SQL, Binary, or Property List (for Mac OS X) , types are inadequate and would require another store type.

Answer (score 4):

Certainly the built-in types should be able to deal with 90% of requirements, but that still leaves 10%...

A few examples, some of which I've seen, some of which are just possibilities:

- Use the "incremental store" type to use Core Data to work with web services, caching content where possible. So a "save" gets converted into a network request to push to a server
- Use a SQL database other than SQLite, possibly MySQL
- Write directly to a custom file format

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a scenario where I have a database on Cloud and it is other than sqlite and at all the time I want it to be in sync with my device database. In that scenario, I could use a custom persistent store in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Very late reply - but some applications may hold sensitive data and you may want to encrypt the data when persisting it.